# What's the proper word naming an electronic system? Administration (Administrative) or Operational?

Tags: word-choice

In our day-to-day business activities, we transfer our records from paper into a cloud-based e-system. Mostly, it's used for tracking information, project progress and a storage place for files and documents. Mostly they're just metadata to source data which coming from places other than this system.

What's the proper term to name this type of system? I thought it would be "Operational system", but "OS" is so commonly used in IT area standing for Microsoft, Android etc. Then I thought it could be "Administration system", but the system is just under 1 specific department of the organization, it may lead people to think its scope boarder, e.g., general operations including HR, IT etc.

Any suggestions from you? thank you!

Comment: Unless you want to be more specific about the scope of the system, I would have thought "IT system" would hit the spot...

Comment: No, Microsoft Widows and Android are Operat**ing** Sysyems. What you are doing can well be described as a operat**ional** system or ""system of operation" . *"Our system of operation is to transfer our daily records to cloud storage."*

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to be more specific to narrow down the scope, so other department won't be disturbed when come across its name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are mixing the terminology from your organisation with similar terminology that is used differently in IT?

For example, in multiple organisations I have worked in, the term 'operational' has been used to refer to areas of the business that carry out core work (eg 'operational teams'), while other terms such as 'administration' or 'support' have been used to describe other teams or services that support the business in other essential ways (eg payroll, human resources) but are not carrying out core business.

When it comes to IT terminology, an 'operating system' always refers to the base software that runs on a machine, controls the hardware, and acts as a platform for other software to run on top of it. Using that term in any other way would be confusing.

In my experience, most software applications that are used to keep track of core business, such as clients, sales, appointments, work flow etc, would be called an *administration system*. For example, hospitals tend to have a *Patient Administration System*; law firms may have a *Practice Administration System*. Even if such a system was used by an area of your business you referred to as 'operational', they would use this system in the administration of their work.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the software applications I was trying to describe. Well, in that way, then "Administration system" shall it be. Thanks!